# Can we have multiple voice mails for different contacts in Android

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am building a cross platform application. How can we add new voice mail messages for different contacts or contact profiles programatically in android or using phonegap.

Example: If contact1 calls the user, he should go into voicemail with message 1. Similarly for other contacts.

Thanks.

Comment: Tell them to call and leave another message?

Comment: I have rephrased my original question. Please check.

Comment: Are you talking about different voicemail greetings?  If so, those are not part of an app, but determined by the telco carrier.

Comment: I thought it could be done with Google voice

Answer (score 2):

> How can we add new voice mail messages for different contacts or contact profiles programatically in android or using phonegap.

Raise approximately 1 trillion USD. Acquire every wireless carrier. Force them to implement support for this. Then modify Android for your devices to offer support for this.

Beyond that, you have no means of affecting what happens at the mobile carrier.